# Rxjs add delay on specific iteration

Tags: rxjs5

I have a stream of numbers e.g 1 - 10 emitted after every 250ms.

```
1 -(250ms)- 2 -(250ms)- 3 -(250ms)- 4 -(250ms)- 5 -(250ms)- 6 and so on..

Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
.zip(Rx.Observable.timer(0, 25), x => x)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

I want to add an added delay after every 3 items. i.e on 3, 6, 9

```
1 -(250ms)- 2 -(250ms)- 3 -(2000ms)- 4 -(250ms)- 5 -(250ms)- 
6 -(2000ms) - 7 -(250ms)- 8 -(250ms)- 9 -(2000ms)- 10
```

How to get this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use the `.range()` operator. Then you can use `.flatMap()`:

```
var s = Rx.Observable.range(1,8);
s1 = s.flatMap(v => {
  var delay = v * 250 + Math.floor(v / 3) * 1750;
  console.log('delay for ', v, ' = ', delay);
  return Rx.Observable.of(v).delay(delay);
});
s1.subscribe(console.log.bind(console, '>> '));
```